# Is there a way to control when puppet sends its report to Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, puppet, jenkins-plugins

As a newbie to puppet, i'am trying to track deployment of my files through puppet plugin in Jenkins. Since by default, puppet track the file resources i'am able to do that.

**My question is whether there is a way to tell puppet to when to send the report to Jenkins?**

In my scenario, i'm getting the file from Jenkins archive, and after that i'm doing a service stop and then unzip the file and copy the content to install location and restart the service.

My requirement is if i can somehow configure puppet to wait until all those resources task run in puppet and if and only if all succeed only, send the report to Jenkins, then i'll be able to know deployment is 100% complete.

**Also would like to know is there a way to notify Jenkins about deployment failures?**

Comment: About 'deployment failures', in job configuration, you define an email to be sent in **Post-build Actions** > **Project Recipient List**

Comment: @PhatH.VU, you mean in Jenkins configuration?. But what i really want is how puppet deployment failure to be notified to jenkins.? how that relationship can be formed so when ever puppet failed to deploy for whatever reason, jenkins get notified

Comment: yep, I missed your idea. :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you can do the next thing:
when the jenkins job starts, run on the puppet agent:

```
puppet agent --disable
```

then:

```
puppet agent -t
EXIT_CODE=$?
if [[ ${EXIT_CODE} == 0 ]] || [[ ${EXIT_CODE} == 2 ]]; then
    true
    exit $?
else
    exit ${EXIT_CODE}
fi
```

That way if puppet status is 0 or 2 - which means if it's run changed successfully or unchanged (successfully) - you will get true.
else, you will exit your shell run with false, and the job will fail.

You can also print comments and such and use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin plugin to make the build green / yellow / red as you like.

Comment: Would this only work in master-less puppet agent? I'm not sure this works in a puppet master-agent scenario.

Comment: I do this in master-agent. What would be different here? The exit code in master-agent is still 0 or 2 :)